# How to improve code snippet, getting indices based on condidion?

Tags: list, performance, numpy, loops, optimization

I would like to get the indices of elements in a list based on a condition. For most cases one can do that with `np.where`. However, once the conditions becomes more complicated things get messy.

In my case, the condition is simply: The element also exists in a second list. How could I write this performantly? I included sample code that works, but is slow due to the for loop and the append for the list. If possible I would like to get rid of both and have performant code. Does anyone have an idea how this can be done?

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randint(4, size=20)
B = [0, 1, 2]
indices = list()
N = len(A)
for i in range(N):
    if A[i] in B:
        indices.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the quickest I could make it

```
[indices.append(i) for i in range(N) if A[i] in B]
```

This one took

```
Program Executed in 0.000104600000000010
```

Your one took

```
Program Executed in 0.000138000000000027
```